# cq include not working, 404 error

Tags: aem

I tried to include a component in another component using following code

```
<%
String fakePath = resource.getPath() + "/nav-tabs";
%>
<cq:include path="<%=fakePath%>" resourceType="ven/components/navMenu"/>
```

When I open the site page and tried to edit the component to author data, following error is coming in the browser console and not able to see the component dialog.

> widgets.js:3318 GET
>   http://localhost:4502/content/ven/global/en/testPage/jcr:content/nav-tabs.infinity.json?_dc=1481236797569
>   404 (Not Found)

I do not see any resource created below the content tree too.

Could any one shed some light on this?

Thanks,
Sri

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you placing this component directly on the page, because resource.getPath() returns http://localhost:4502/content/ven/global/en/testPage/jcr:content in your case. You can use page templates to create initial content when creating the page.

For components you can use cq:template resource:

Just place cq:template resource beneath your component. As soon you add a new component it should copy the content of it into your resource (similar to page templates)

In your case: _cq_template.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0"
      jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    <nav-tabs
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="ven/components/navMenu"/>
</jcr:root>
```

Comment: thank you for the help. Doesn't sling create the synthatic resource, if I place the component directly on page ?

Comment: I think sling will still try to render not existing resources with given resourceType, the problem is in ext.js dialog implementation. It expects the resource to exists to render the dialog.